# i am a young programmer i understand somethings but not why does %d stand for integer

Tags: c

I haven't programmed for long so I'm not used to all these. could anyone please give an answer?

I didn't actually try anything so i just decided to go ask someone for help on the problem.

Comment: It stands for decimal. You may use `%i` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A small tip for new programmers, take the [tour] read [ask] and before you ask next time, do some research first.

Answer (score 0):

The %d in c is a format specifier that is used as a placeholder in the printf() function that represents an integer value that will be printed to the console. The letter `d` in `%d` stands for "decimal" where it refers to the 10 base numbering system used by humans.

Comment: these arent obvious like %i for int, %d is int and %x is hex.